# Why does my Query use a Bitmap Heap Scan

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index-tuning, postgresql-performance

my simple query is not really fast and I don't know why my query is using Bitmap Heap Scan.

```sql
explain analyze verbose 
SELECT connections, epoch_time 
FROM connections 
WHERE host_name = 'xyz.z' 
ORDER BY epoch_time;
```

Output:

```
                                                               QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=3257.93..3316.47 rows=23415 width=13) (actual time=8.607..9.624 rows=23259 loops=1)
   Output: connections, epoch_time
   Sort Key: connections.epoch_time
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1859kB
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.connections  (cost=545.88..1558.57 rows=23415 width=13) (actual time=1.341..5.840 rows=23259 loops=1)
         Output: connections, epoch_time
         Recheck Cond: ((connections.host_name)::text = 'xyz.z'::text)
         Heap Blocks: exact=651
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_host_name  (cost=0.00..540.03 rows=23415 width=0) (actual time=1.266..1.266 rows=23259 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((connections.host_name)::text = 'xyz.z'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.171 ms
 Execution Time: 10.405 ms
(12 rows)
```

The table has 97806 rows and I have created an index on the field epoch_time.  The table has 4 columns (id, host_name, connections, epoch_time)

Comment: The query only needs 10ms (that's 0.01 second) - how fast do you need that to be?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your reply. My php - Files load slow and I think the reason is that my sql - statements performing not well (this is just 1 statement but my php files executing 20 sql statements like this). I think that if my query use Index Only Scan instead of Bimap Heap Scan then the query would be faster

Comment: Is this query representative of the other 19?  Why would you need to return 1/4 of the table, 20 times?  What is the definition of the index you think it should be using instead?  Is the table recently/frequently vacuumed?

Comment: @jjanes yes the table is recently vacuumed. I just thought maybe my index is not the right one. Because I have charts and the charts include 4 different host_name types. And this is just one table. The structure of  the query is the same but in multiple different tables. Is there a way to speed up the order by?  Because if I leave the order by the query takes 6 ms instead of 10 or 12. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is doubtful whether this query needs speeding up, but if anything can improve the performance, it would be

```
CREATE INDEX ON connections (host_name, epoch_time) INCLUDE (connections);
```

This assumes that there is actually a column `connections`; if that is a whole-row reference, you cannot get an index-only scan.

Make sure the table is vacuumed often.

Also, bear in mind that each index slows down data modifications. So use it only if query speed is paramount.